# Unity3d:Detect a collision between an image and a sphere

Tags: unity, 2d, collision-detection, 3d

So, I just realized, an `image` with `BoxCollider2D` wont detect any collision with `Sphere` with `SphereCollider`.

I tried adding a `BoxCollider` to my image, but it behaves in a weird manner (The Canvas position keeps shifting)

So, I can see the only way for it to work is adding a 2D Collider to the sphere? Is there any other better way to solve it? Adding a 2D Collider to the sphere wont cover the whole area

Comment: A SphereCollider is a 3D object, handled by Unity's 3D physics engine, PhysX. A BoxCollider2D is a 2D physics object, handled by Unity's 2D physics engine, Box2D. These are two separate worlds that don't interact. What exactly is your expected behaviour for collisions between these two objects, and how do your results so far differ from what you want? (ie. what specifically is "weird" about the way the canvas position shifts in response to collisions?) The more precisely you can describe your problem and what you want, the better we can help you solve it.

Comment: @DMGregory So, this is a VR application. My image is a reticule. The image is directed by my head movement. So, I want to trigger a function when my reticule touches the sphere. The problem here is, the Canvas floats towards the camera every time.

Comment: @DMGregory The reticule is supposed to be 4 units apart from the camera (head). As soon as I disable the BoxCollider from the image, the Canvas stops floating towards the Camera, and behaves the correct way.

Comment: It sounds like what you really want here is a spherecast or boxcast query along the line of sight, not a collision response.

Comment: @DMGregory So, should I remove the box collider from the image? and I have 4 spheres in the scene, so I should check which collider my spherecast is hitting in the `Update` function?

Comment: You tell us: does that achieve your goal? If so, post it as an answer. If not, edit your question to describe what problem you're experiencing when you try it.